# sumproduct containing other functions in excel

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I would like to ask to help me with sumproduct function. I have this formula at the moment:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('One Pager Grid'!B10:B1000='SCO One Pager'!A49)*('One Pager Grid'!D10:D1000='SCO One Pager'!B49)*('One Pager Grid'!S10:S1000))
```

I am multiplying values in columns B and D based on criteria and that should be multiplied by value from column with specific month (jan - dec). I woud like to replace this part of formula `('One Pager Grid'!S10:S1000)`.
I tried to use `=MATCH(U2,'One Pager Grid'!9:9,)` and I got column number. That cell U2 contains month in format "JAN" and sheet One Pager Grid in row 9 has all months. Month can be changed in cell U2 so I can get column numbers from 5 to 19.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Use: `INDEX('One Pager Grid'!$10:$1000,0,MATCH(U2,'One Pager Grid'!9:9,))`

Comment: great it worked, thanks